# How do I use order on my dataProvider in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, dataprovider

Below is my dataProvider that I would like to order (ascending) by `account_code`.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
'query' => Accounts::find()->where('account_type=1'),
'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: I tried this but it failed misreably.

 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Accounts::find()->where('account_type=1'),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
 orderBy =>[
  'account_code' => SORT_ASC,
 ],
 ]);

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['account_code'=>SORT_ASC]],
```